# Regex all character plus some punctuation character

Tags: jquery, regex, character

My code works fine for characters `a-z` and `.,?!`. Is it possible allow all Cyrilic (Russian, Serbian) and Scandinavian characters as well as `.,?!`?

```js
$('#myInput').bind('keydown', function(event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 8: // Backspace
    case 9: // Tab
    case 13: // Enter
    case 37: // Left
    case 38: // Up
    case 39: // Right
    case 40: // Down
      break;
    default:
      var regex = new RegExp("^[\wa-zA-Z0-9.,?!/]+$");
      var key = event.key;
      if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: The duplicate covers the theory of the answer. For the actual implementation of Cyrillic characters you need `\u0400-\u04FF`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  I need all chaacter not only Cyrillic + .,?!

Comment: Then you'll need to find their unicode values and add them to the regex